# foreach loop in codeigniter - in controller or view?

Tags: codeigniter

Im learning CodeIgniter and trying to follow best practices.

I was wondering where is the best place to execute a foreach loop?

Lets say I have a Model where I query the database and return all the results.

Then should I execute foreach in the Controller? Or rather View? Why?

Comment: It depends on your scenario. If you want to display the results to user then _Model_ -> send results to, _Controller_ -> _View_ -> your `foreach($withResults)` loop.

Comment: Yes, but I can also do the foreach loop in the controller and still pass results to the view.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you're trying to do. If you're looping through results and outputting HTML, then I would recommend you do that in the view. If you're looping through results to do something to your data then outputting *that* to the view, then that logic would belong in the controller (or model).

I try to keep my views as PHP-free as possible, so when I have to loop through I tend to use alternate syntax for the loop. Here's an example:

```
<?php foreach ($x as $y) : ?>
<div>
    <h2><?php echo $y['title']; ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $y['content']; ?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The above ensures that should someone that only knows frontend development need to tweak the view, it's very clear what's happening there.